# How to use pagination for the asset publisher custom application display template in Liferay?

Tags: liferay-6, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created one ADT for asset publisher and here im fetching all the documents from a specific folder ,here my problem is that we want to use existing pagination,we have configured the simple pagination, but still the result not coming properly.so is there any alternate way to use the existing pagination with our custom ADT.

Thanks & Regards,

P.v.B.Raju.

Comment: I can able to complete my requirement but I haven't used existing pagination

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to paginate in Freemarker by default. For custom pagination, you have to override Liferay's core JSP [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.x/portal-web/docroot/html/taglib/ui/page_iterator/start.jsp), which is very unfortunate. If you've found another solution, please share it here.